# Допустимые названия таблицы в базе данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, table

Добрый день.

подскажите как можно называть таблицу в БД, к примеру...

prefix_table

prefix.table

prefixTable

из примера, какие названия допустимы а какие нет?

Comment: точка это элемент языка, разделяющий имя схемы и таблицы или таблицы и колонки. все остальное в названиях допустимо

Answer (score 1):

Все 3 приведённые [названия допустимы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html).

Есть различия в допустимых обращениях: вы не сможете написать

```
select id from prefix.table
```

Подразумевая таблицу с именем `prefix.table`. Разделение точкой разделяет имя базы, схемы данных и имя таблицы (в терминологии mysql схемы данных не реализованы). Вы должны будете указывать имя таблицы в специальных кавычках:

```
select id from `prefix.table`
```

Либо, если [`sql_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) установлен в соответствие стандарту `ANSI_QUOTES`:

```
select id from "prefix.table"
```

Касательно использования имён в разных регистрах - есть нюансы в зависимости [от используемой файловой системы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

---

В итоге имена с точками всегда требуют использования кавычек и при их отсутствии дадут ошибку отсутствия базы данных или таблицы. Плюс будут удивлять читающих ваши запросы. Регистрозависимые имена таблиц могут вызвать проблемы при переносе на другую файловую систему. Имена же в нижнем регистре с использованием нижнего подчёркивания для разделения слов используются часто, соответствуют стандарту SQL и проблем как правило не вызывают. Я написал "как правило" потому что всё-таки могут попадаться в [списках зарезервированных слов](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) - такие имена тоже можно использовать, но обращаться к ним возможно только с использованием кавычек.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Legal_names.html). Потом можете прочитать эту статью на Хабре: [Как думать на SQL?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/305926/) ( это для запросов уже )